# How do I downgrade to a kernel version that I have previously uninstalled

Tags: 10.10, kernel, downgrade

I am running kernel version: 2.6.35-27-generic

I want kernel version: 2.6.35-22-generic OR 2.6.35-25-generic

I have previously uninstalled both of the previous. A few scripts that I forgot to test (and worked in old kernels) no longer work in 35-27

I think .35-22 would be the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check whether these versions are still in the repositories with:

`sudo aptitude search linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic` (or 35-25 for the other version)

If they are indeed still there, just install the one you want with:

`sudo aptitude install linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic`

otherwise, follow this [link (for 2.6.35-22)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic) or [this (for 2.6.35-25)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick-updates/admin/linux-image-2.6.35-25-generic)

Comment: Thanks - I thought I had tried that but obviously something stopped the installation. Works now.

Comment: Glad to hear that ;-)

Comment: Woops - I got the script working in the new kernel :). At least this question will be a resource for others trying to find this out.